# Can I use Vue.js CLI in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js and would like to know if it is possible to use Vue CLI in Visual Studio ASP .NET MVC Project. I have mastered most of the features the CDN offer and to unlock more, and I discover one has to run the Vue CLI to be able to do that.

Comment: Maybe you need to be a little more specific about what job you want to integrate with vs. There's no difference between vs code and vs and the vue cli.

Comment: I am trying to use the Vue CLI in ASP .Net MVC project

Comment: Do you have any concrete question? Yes, you can use Vue CLI in ASP, in fact, those technologies don't clash with each other. To use VUE CLI need node/npm installed in your pc. You can create your MVC project and then in the root create a vue cli project or move an existing VUE CLI to the root of MVC. Then you want to redirect all routes to a controller let's say home controller and that home controller will return the index view. In vue cli, you need to output the generated HTML to the index view or put a specific location in the controller.

Comment: This may help you, there's a lot of vue and asp net core 2 tutorials you can check out the architecture and replicate in the mvc5. https://medium.com/@hyounoosung/integrating-vue-js-2-0-to-net-mvc5-project-f97eb5a5b3ad

Comment: I've used this template to create Vue.js projects in Visual Studio using MVC ASP.NET Core https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-Vue-starter   Hope it helps.